# Hide and show column of a table based on click of the button in Angular

Tags: angular

I have implemented a dynamic table in angular 7. If you see I am generating duplicate columns. You will see Add Side letter on the first of every pair. What I want is the duplicate column should be hidden by default and should appear only when Add side letter button of its pair is clicked.

Here is the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/76w4zhnu/

Html

```
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
      <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
        <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
           <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[3]">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn mr-1" style="float: left;">Add Side Letter</button>
           </td>
           <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[3]">

           </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

Component

```
 public ColumnNames: string[] = ['Legal Class Name', 'Last Edited' , 'Legal Class ID',''];
```

Comment: first of all. you variable ColumnNames is actually your rows and your data the property description, thats what the column is

Comment: I think you should use ```groupBy``` by lodash or RxJS. Group you data by the description, then all you data that correspons to Class B will together then you loop display the data then you won't have duplicates

Comment: Sorry for not being clear . The issues is not of duplicates here or getting rid of duplicates . Those columns are intentionally created to hold records. I need ability to hide or show that entire section on click of button

Answer (score 0):

please check the answer to your other question about related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448688/angular-creating-an-additional-column-beside-the-existing-column-in-a-dynamicall)

well, if you want, make a more confortable code using an array of object, not two arrays

```
columnsDef=[
  {description:'Legal Class name',key:'Description',duplicate:true},
  {description:'Last Edited',key:'AuditSummary',duplicate:true},
  {description:'Legal Class ID',key:'Id',duplicate:false}
]
```

And your .html

```
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
    <tr *ngFor="let c of columnsDef;let i=index">
        <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c.description }}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
            <td>{{f[c.key]}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="c.duplicate">{{f[c.key]}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="c.duplicate=!c.duplicate">click</button></td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</table>
```